# How to allow key entry in a textbox while capturing it in a window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF window which captures both the KeyDown and KeyUp events. However, there is a TextBox in this window, and if a user is typing in that textbox, I want the general capture to effectively be ignored. The trouble I'm running into is that my efforts to ignore the general capture when typing in that textbox result in the user being unable to type in that textbox at all.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="600" Width="500" 
    KeyDown="MainWindow_OnKeyDown" 
    KeyUp="MainWindow_OnKeyUp">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxAllowed" KeyDown="TextBoxAllowed_OnKeyDown" KeyUp="TextBoxAllowed_OnKeyUp" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            // take action using the value of e.Key
            // should not be triggered when TextBoxAllowed has focus
            // but should be triggered otherwise
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            // take action using the value of e.Key
            // should not be triggered when TextBoxAllowed has focus
            // but should be triggered otherwise
        }

        private void TextBoxAllowed_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void TextBoxAllowed_OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like it so that when TextBoxAllowed has focus, the user can type in it normally, and that the MainWindow_OnKey* event handlers are *not* triggered. But when that field doesn't have focus, if any typing takes place, then I want those key handlers to kick in. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You can just check if the text box has focus in your window event handler and don't do anything if it does have focus.

Comment: I was going to say the same as roryap.  e.Handled seems like the wrong idea for your textboxes

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
    private void TextBoxAllowed_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!yourTextBox.HasFocus())
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```